# Change citep{} style from (NAME, YEAR) to (Name (YEAR))

Tags: cross-referencing, citing

I am a bloody noob regarding LaTeX and in the process of writing my bachelor thesis with it. However, my University has a citation standard, which i cannot achieve at the moment. Following styles are used:

```
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{ecta1}
```

Now if I want to make a corresponding reference (not a one to one citation) I normally use the following command (Shleifer 1993 as example):

```
\citep{Shleifer1993}
```

This shows up like this in the text:

> (Shleifer, 1993)

What I would want is that it shows up like this:

> (Shleifer (1993))

How do I do that?